# List - Strings - Textfiles

Tags: c++, string, list, text-files, combinations

I've got a few questions concerning text files,list and strings.

I wonder if it is possible to put in a code which reads the text in a textfile,and then using "string line;" or something else to define each new row of the text and turn all of them into one list. So I can sort the rows, remove a row or two or even all of them or search through the text for a specific row.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: well, I'm using c++ in Borland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, you'd typically do this with an std::vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> data;

std::string temp;

while (std::getline(infile, temp))
    data.push_back(temp);
```

Sorting them would then look like:

```
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
```

Deleting row N would look like:

```
data.erase(data.begin() + N);
```

Answer (score 1):

The language wasn't specified but I would imagine the design behind it would be the same:

- Read in your data and store each piece of text in some 'string' structure
- Store each piece of data in a List type object (eg, std::vector in c++)
- Define or utilize some interface to perform the requested operations

I suppose then it will be just a matter of which language.  So yes it is possible.